# Converting a hexidecimal string to a byte array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, casting, byte

So, as the title states, I am trying to convert a string into a byte array.

So, I have this string: `string bytes = "2C 2D 3B 27"`,
and I want to convert it from a string, to a byte array, without actually converting the strings contents to a byte array.

So, turn this: `string bytes = "2C 2D 3B 27"`

to this: `byte[] byteArray = { \x2C, \x2D, \x3B, \x27 }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var bytes = "2C 2D 3B 27";
var byteArray = bytes.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```